# math.stackexchange has so many good mathematicians, were you all good at maths since school?

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm afraid this question will be kicked out but I have to ask this.
Were you all mathematicians brilliant and had good maths brain since you were kid?
I was very bad in maths when I was in grade 8 then got better at it till high school. But I've been programming for 6 years after graduation and now getting back to do Research degree. I find myself to be stuck, can't make sense of anything, even basic stuffs. Does that mean I am not good at maths? or may be it isn't my cup of tea?

Comment: I'm not one of the more active/prolific members on this site, but for what its worth I remember struggling immensely  with working with negative nubmers in middle school and now I'm minoring in math undergrad and thoroughly enjoyed both analysis and abstract algebra.

Comment: Betta on meta. :)

Comment: My friends always said I was just an average mathematician, but I always felt that was kind of mean :O

Comment: "All things are difficult before they are easy." - Thomas Fuller

Comment: Is there an erdos number for someone who has comment on the question by person with an Erdos number?

Comment: @Sebastian: I was always in love with mathematics -- I knew by the time I was ten that I wanted to teach it at the university level -- and good at it, but I've certainly known mathematicians who came to it much later. I don't think that you should worry about age, and you should give yourself some time to get your feet on the ground. (I don't think that it means much, but since you ask, I do have an Erdős number of $3$.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without knowing more about your background and your teachers and the curriculum that you've been subjected to, it's hard to say much in specific.  However, I **highly recommend** that you read (at least the first dozen pages of) Paul Lockhart's essay:  [*A Mathematician's Lament*](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf).

Enjoying mathematics is key, and the world is awash with misconceptions about what that is.  Creativity and an appetite for solving problems is probably more important than having excellent memorization and procedural skills; the latter skills are, unfortunately, often mistaken for being "good" at math.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I was a programmer but always wanted to do maths, I just enjoy it although I struggle a lot, A LOT. I left my well paying programming job to get down to this path. I'm starting research in cryptography and have started learning and my supervisor is a good one. However, I have lot of doubt in myself. Not sure if I am really made for maths. All over internet I see stories of genius people, young talents. Since I'm now 30, I feel less confident.